Cosmic expansion: FLRW metric vs Distance
What is the conceptual difference between the FLRW metric expansion of spacetime and the observed increasing of cosmic distances between two light-emitting sources according to the Hubble Law?


Rene Kail asked: "What is the conceptual difference between the FLRW metric expansion of spacetime and the observed increasing of cosmic distances between two light-emitting sources according to the Hubble Law?"

The FLRW metric is not expanding spacetime but expanding space, if you're looking for an expanding spacetime theory see here.
There is no difference in the FLRW metric and the observed increase of proper distances due to the Hubble law since the FLRW  (in comoving, proper or whatever coordinates) is the metric that describes the Hubble law, so the answer to your question is "none".

The difference is only on local distances where we have inhomogeneities and the peculiar velocities are comparable to the recessional velocities, but at the cosmological distances you asked about the latter dominate and there is no notable difference between the FLRW and the real universe since on those scales the universe is uniform.

TL;DR: The former is a cause and the latter is an effect
Universal expansion is something that’s just happening - the Universe’s scale factor is going up. As a result, cosmic distances appear to increase.
Explanation with simple calculus
Imagine two objects, one at position $A$ and one at position $B$, for vectors (or equivalently points) $A$ and $B$ on a manifold. How do you measure the distance between them?
In Euclidean space, this is easily found with something akin to Pythagoras’s theorem. Let $\mathrm{d}s$ represent the distance between the two objects, and let the manifold have three spatial dimensions, $x$, $y$, and $z$. Then, the distance between the two objects is
$$\mathrm{d}s^2= \mathrm{d}x^2+ \mathrm{d}y^2+\mathrm{d}z^2.$$
That should be clear enough. (In reality, this is an abuse of notation of sorts; you would ordinarily need to integrate over a straight line between the two objects, but let’s assume that the manifold’s structure is uniform so we don’t need to worry about that.) Here, $\mathrm{d}x$ represents the distance along the $x$-axis between the objects, and so on for $\mathrm{d} y$ and $\mathrm{d} z$ as well. Using this equation, we can assign numerical values to the “distance” between two points (technically called “proper distance”).
This equation, called the metric, is one part of the manifold (the other being the set of all points $A$, $B$, etc.). We formally describe it with the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$, and generally define the metric as
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=g_{\mu\nu} \mathrm{d}X^\mu \mathrm{d}X^\nu,$$
where

$\mathrm{d}X^0= \mathrm{d}t$,
$\mathrm{d}X^1= \mathrm{d}x$,
$\mathrm{d}X^2= \mathrm{d}y$,
$\mathrm{d}X^3= \mathrm{d}z$,

and the indices $\mu$ and $\nu$ are summed over. Here the superscripts are interpreted as indices, not exponents.
The metric we just described is that of Euclidean space. Notably, in Euclidean space, relativity doesn’t exist (i.e. time dilation isn’t a thing), and space doesn’t expand. In the FLRW metric, which describes an expanding spacetime, one has
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=-c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2+a^2(t)(\mathrm{d}x^2+ \mathrm{d}y^2+ \mathrm{d}z^2).$$
Here, $a(t)$ is a function (its square appears in the metric) that describes the “scale factor”, and as far as we know monotonically increases. Also present is the $-c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2$ term, which effectively adds a speed limit of $c$ (for complicated reasons; out of scope for the question, you can effectively ignore that term if the objects under consideration are moving slowly and not under the influence of strong gravity.)
Using the FLRW metric, consider $A$ and $B$ again. Say that when $a(t)=1$, you use the FLRW metric to find that they are one meter apart. Yay! For example, if we’re considering a constant-time slice where the $-c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2$ term becomes irrelevant, we could note that their coordinate distance apart on the $x$-axis is $\mathrm{d}x=1$, while $\mathrm{d}y= \mathrm{d}z=0$. Thus, $\mathrm{d}s=1$.
Then, the Universe expands. $a(t)$ goes up to 2. The coordinates of $A$ and $B$ have not changed: $\mathrm{d}x$ is still 1, and other displacements are still zero. But when you calculate the proper distance $\mathrm{d}s$, you get a result of two meters. Because the Universe has expanded (i.e. $a(t)$ has gone up), the proper distance between the objects has increased, despite both being “at rest” relative to each other!
Finally, because $\mathrm{d}s$ is changing over time, you can express the differential $\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}$, which gives how fast objects seem to be moving away due to expansion; specifically, it’s describing the rate of change of proper distance with respect to time. Dropping $-c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2$, one finds that this speed is proportional to two things: the rate of change of $a(t)$ (i.e. the rate at which the Universe is expanding) - call this rate of change $k$ - and the Euclidean distance $\sqrt{\mathrm{d}x^2+ \mathrm{d}y^2+ \mathrm{d}z^2}$ - call this distance $d$.
So, we have:
$$v=kd.$$
And as it turns out, $k$ is really the Hubble constant. Substituting that, you get exactly what is observed in the Universe.
In other words, to answer your question, the Universe’s expansion is a change in $a(t)$, which causes proper distances to go up. One is a cause, the other is an effect.
Why use the FLRW metric?
Because it matches reality. We’ve observed our Universe to be approximately flat, which the FLRW spacetime is, and we’ve observed that the Universe expands over time, which the FLRW metric allows for.
